# Get all user processes via script run by cron job

Tags: php, cron

I have a corn job that executes a PHP script every minute and execute **processchecker.php**. The script **processchecker.php** will then check from user process, which one contains the filename **backgroundprocess.php**.

This works perfectly if iam triggering these files manually by visiting their respective URLs.

Problem comes in when i automate the process as a cron job which for some reason does not return the processes that i am looking for. Cron jobs seem to be running with no user account and i am  suspecting i need a method of listing all processes especially those started by the cron job itself.

**processcheck.php**

```
<?php
    exec("ps aux", $output, $result);
    $found=0;

    foreach ($output AS $line) if(strpos($line, "backgroundprocess.php")){ $found=$found+1;};

    if($found==0){
       //service not running start it all over again
       if (!$pid = shell_exec("nohup php backgroundprocess.php > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!")) return false; 
    }else{
        //service is Already running
    }
?>
```

From what i am seeing `exec("ps aux", $output, $result);` is not fetching processes started by the cron job itself......and therefore my background process will always be started over and over.

Please note, all this is on a remote vps server and i am using cpanel.

**EDIT**
Result is 0
Output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
    [1] => rycjptbb     1  0.0  0.0   6324   600 ?        SN   14:51   0:00 jailshell (rycjptbb) [init] ell -c nohup php public_html/processchecker.php > /dev/null & echo $!
    [2] => rycjptbb     3  1.0  0.0 248940 12308 ?        SN   14:51   0:00 php public_html/processchecker.php
    [3] => rycjptbb     4  0.0  0.0 110236  1112 ?        RN   14:51   0:00 ps aux
)
```

Comment: log the 'ps aux' command output to a file so you can check it

Comment: sometimes it gives an integer 1..as the result

Comment: And what is the output in those cases? The command should return 0 as the exit code (the $result argument). So you should only consider the output valid when $result contains 0.

Comment: @gontrollez .....I have just edited with the sample output..please read the edit

Comment: @Lukesoft have you found a solution for this? I've been struggling on the same issue for the past couple of days

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you just want to check if there is not other same process currently running.
For example, if process1.php runs every 1 minute, and the runtime can take lets say 3 minutes, you dont want another process to run in the second minute.
If that is your case then you can check if there is another process with the same name exists with this:

```
function is_other_process_exists()
{
    $my_name = 'xxx'; //your process name, e.g. process1.php
    $ps = `ps gax`;
    $psLines = explode("\n", $ps);
    array_pop($psLines);
    $myLines = array();
    foreach ( $psLines as $psLine )
    {
        if (strstr($psLine, $my_name))
        {
            $myLines[] = $psLine;
        }
    }
    if ( count($myLines) > 1 ) {
        $myPid = posix_getpid();
        echo "process is already running with process id {$myPid}";
        exit;
    }
}
```